# PHP Slim 404 not found when uploaded to 000webhost

Tags: php, slim

I am new in php slim and I started with simple program. When I uploaded it on 000webhost I got 404 error
my file contained  just index.php ,I uploaded slim framework with my files
index.php

```
   <?php
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $app->get('/users','getUsers');
    $app->get('/updates','getUserUpdates');
    $app->post('/updates', 'insertUpdate');
    $app->delete('/updates/delete/:update_id','deleteUpdate');
    $app->get('/users/search/:query','getUserSearch');

    $app->run();

    function getUsers() {
    echo "getUsers method";
    }

    function getUserUpdates() {
    echo "getUserUpdates method";
    }

    function getUserUpdate($update_id) {
    echo "getUserUpdate method";
    }

    function insertUpdate() {
    echo "insertUpdate method";
    }

    function deleteUpdate($update_id) {
    echo "deleteUpdate method";
    }

    function getUserSearch($query) {
    echo "getUserSearch method";
    }
    ?>
```

.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 when you try to load index.php then the problem does not reside in your code. You should check and make sure to upload index.php in correct folder (document root) on your host.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not uploading .htaccess and index.php in the document root correctly. 404 means, the webserver (Apache/Nginx) is not able to find the index.php file as specified in .htaccess.

In case of Apache ensure mod_rewrite is enabled.